# What does dry-run do in optparse Python?

Tags: python, optparse

What's the functionality of the [`dry-run` option in the optparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html#terminology) of Python?

Comment: And, as usual, if you are using Python 2.7+ (or even 2.6+), you should use `argparse` instead of `optparse`. See http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dry run* is a generic expression in many fields, [including computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_run_%28testing%29), meaning that a certain operation should be performed or simulated limiting its dangerous effects.

**It is up to you to associate that option to something meaningful in your code.** For example: if your script normally removes files from the hard drive, the `--dry-run` option should only print out a list of the files that *would have been deleted* if the script would have been ran *without* the `--dry-run` option.

`--dry-run` is just a conventional name for that option, but you could implement the same functionality with any other name (e.g `--simulate-only` or `--dont-screw-up`).

Comment: --dont-screw-up will definitely be effective :)

Answer (score 3):

`--dry-run` has no special meaning for the `optparse` module.

It is just an example used in the documentation of the module.

Comment: it means it is simply an user defined option?

Comment: Yes, just one option the user can define. `optparse` assigns no special meaning to it, it's not even mentioned in the module's source code